# Getting public key from digital signature

Tags: java, security, encryption, encoding, cryptography

I am working on a java based licensing project. I have a digital certificate file and the data  for which the signature was generated. Is there some API or means to get the public key from these information?  Basically Public Key from the data and digital certificate information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague IMHO.

> I have a digital certificate file and
>   the data for which the signature was
>   generated

If the certificate file has the public key used to verify the signature then you can load it using standard java apis (assuming X509 Certificates).

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("PathToCertificate");
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

Once you have the public key you can use it to verify the signature.
Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry for sounding vague. Let me clarify. I have a digital signature and the data for which the signature was generated. Now I want to verify this signature. I am following this tutorial for this --

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/versig.html  . However, I don't have the public key which is required. Is there any way I can get that ?

Comment: Signature does not store information of the signing certificate.You need  to have the certificate as well.This is not a problem though since the signing certificate is a public document and you should have it as well

Answer (score 2):

If you digital signature is of format PKCS#7 - **not** detached, then there is a possibility that the sender would have included the certificate as a part of the digital signature.

You will be required to parse the signature to get the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bouncy Castle API](http://bouncycastle.org) has a `SignedData` class which has a method for getting certificate(s).

Answer (score 0):

The certificate must bear a reference to the id of the key used to certify your data. From this key, should be able to contact the corresponding certificate authority and obtain the public key by providing its id. It may be available from a public repository too.

The id of the certificate authority should also appear on this certificate.

There are APIs available for sure, but the question is, which framework are you using for digital signatures? Do you have its name? Do you know the certificate type?